# Convert ZIP file structure to treeview recursively

Tags: vb.net

I have been wondering if there is anyway to make my code below function in a recursive fashion.

I did look at some examples here at Stack Overflow but they all seem to be solely dealing with existing file structures on a local drive.

Zip files have no file structure. Only lists of full paths.

Before I get blasted for not posting any attempts at coding this, I have no idea how to do it. Recursion is voodoo magic I have never been able to code correctly with out example work.

Below is a solution I worked out. If anyone has been trying to sort this out.. Try this. It works but only will handle 8 levels of nesting. It can be expanded easy enough once you understand how the code works.

If this can be converted in to something more compact and possibly faster, I'd like to try and code it with some guidance.

```
Module modZipFolderResolver
Public root As root_
Public Structure root_
    Public node() As root_
    Public name As String
    Public index As Integer
    Public isDir As Boolean
    Public count As Integer
    Dim n As TreeNode
    Public Function find(f As String, ByRef idx As Integer)
        If node Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        For k = 0 To Me.node.Length - 1
            If node(k).name = f Then
                idx = k
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function
    Public Sub add(ByRef s As String, ByRef idx As Integer, ByVal fullname As String, ByRef p_node As TreeNode, ByVal isDir As Boolean)
        ReDim Preserve Me.node(Me.count + 1)
        idx = Me.count
        node(Me.count) = New root_
        node(Me.count).name = s
        '------------------------------------
        'add node
        Dim nn As New TreeNode 'create new treevire node
        nn.Tag = fullname
        nn.Text = Me.node(Me.count).name
        If isDir Then ' set image index based on type
            Me.node(Me.count).isDir = True
            nn.SelectedImageIndex = 2
            nn.ImageIndex = 2
            nn.Name = "dir" 'used for evauation when clicked
        Else
            Me.node(Me.count).isDir = False
            nn.SelectedImageIndex = 1
            nn.ImageIndex = 0
            nn.Name = ""
        End If
        '------------------------------------
        ' make a new one if its blank
        If p_node Is Nothing Then
            p_node = New TreeNode
            p_node.Text = Me.name
        End If
        Me.node(Me.count).n = New TreeNode
        Me.node(Me.count).n = nn
        p_node.Nodes.Add(Me.node(Me.count).n)
        '------------------------------------
        Me.count += 1
    End Sub
End Structure

Public Sub build_tree()
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'create the root node
    root = New root_
    GC.Collect() ' clean up garbage if we just killed existing data
    root.n = New TreeNode
    root.n.SelectedImageIndex = 2
    root.n.ImageIndex = 2
    root.n.Text = frmTreeList.tv_filenames.SelectedNode.Text
    root.n.Name= "dir"
    frmTreeList.tv_contents.Nodes.Add(root.n) 'Add to treeview
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'now the fun up part. Create the nested tree structure.
    Dim indexes(9) As Integer 'used to keep track of where we are in the tree structure
    Dim isDir As Boolean = False ' flag for setting up image index
    For Each ent In current_package
        Dim ext = Path.GetExtension(ent.FileName)
        If ext.Length > 0 Then 'is this entry a file or directory?
            isDir = False
        Else
            isDir = True
        End If
        Dim a = ent.FileName.Split("/")
        For i = 0 To 8 ' 8 levels deep enough?
            If a.Length = 2 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If i > a.Length - 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            For k = i To a.Length - 1
                If a(k) = "" Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                Dim idx As Integer
                Select Case k
                    Case 0
                        If root.find(a(0), idx) Then
                            indexes(0) = idx
                        Else
                            root.add(a(0), idx, ent.FileName, root.n, isDir)
                            indexes(0) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 1
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).find(a(1), idx) Then
                            indexes(1) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).add(a(1), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(1) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 2
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).find(a(2), idx) Then
                            indexes(2) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).add(a(2), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(2) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 3
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).find(a(3), idx) Then
                            indexes(3) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).add(a(3), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(3) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 4
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).find(a(4), idx) Then
                            indexes(4) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).add(a(4), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(4) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 5
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).find(a(5), idx) Then
                            indexes(5) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).add(a(5), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(5) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 6
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).find(a(6), idx) Then
                            indexes(6) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).add(a(6), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(6) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 7
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).node(indexes(6)).find(a(7), idx) Then
                            indexes(7) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).node(indexes(6)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).node(indexes(6)).add(a(7), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(7) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case 8
                        If root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).node(indexes(6)).node(indexes(7)).find(a(8), idx) Then
                            indexes(8) = idx
                        Else
                            Dim n = root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).node(indexes(6)).node(indexes(7)).n
                            root.node(indexes(0)).node(indexes(1)).node(indexes(2)).node(indexes(3)).node(indexes(4)).node(indexes(5)).node(indexes(6)).node(indexes(7)).add(a(8), idx, ent.FileName, n, isDir)
                            indexes(8) = idx
                            Exit For
                        End If
                End Select
            Next 'k
        Next 'i
    Next 'each ent
End Sub
End Module
```

This code works well and produces a treeview like this. i'm just hoping someone can shed light on maybe speeding this up using recursion.
[image: TreeView Image]

Comment: Most likely the reason you have no idea is because you're trying to go straight from idea to code.  Don't do that.  If you had to do this with pen and paper, I bet you could.  That means that you must know the steps involved in going from data to solution.  That means that you can write down those steps, refining and formalising them.  That's something anyone can do as it's not programming.  Once you've done that, you have an algorithm that can be implemented any way and in any language you choose.  Only when you have an algorithm should you try to write code. What's your algorithm?

Comment: I agree with that 100% but I have no algorithm other than this linear approach. I'll flip my note book to a new page and try to figure out how to pass the needed variables back in to a recursive routine. When I get this working, I'll post it as an answer.

Thanks for the feed back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of an algorithm, I would do it as follows: -

For each path: -
Split the path into an array of strings by the "/" character.
Pass this array into a new function along with the root node and an index of 0, to indicate that that is where you are up to.

The function should: -
Get the path component for the index passed in
Find or create the child node within the node passed in as a parameter that matches the path component
If the index passed in is equal to the length of the path component array -1 then return the found/created child node
Else the function should return the result of a call to itself, passing in the child node and the index which was passed in +1

This function should create nodes as needed and return the Node for the path

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution though it seems to be just slightly slower. Probably because of having to return back through the call stack. I'll setup a timer and call the old version and the new one and I'll use the fastest version.
This is not limited to just zip files.. any list of file paths will generate a correctly built TreeView.

The advantage of the new method is, there is no limit to the depth of nesting where, the old version is limited to 8 unless the code is expanded.

Just had a idea.. Check how deep the split array of the path is and if its over 8 call the new version, otherwise, call the old version.

UPDATE: I did some time studies and the new version IS slower.

The results of different sized zip files

```
==================================
Path Count: 10756
New method: 0.328ms
Old method: 0.275ms

==================================
Path Count: 11860
New method: 0.338ms
Old method: 0.287ms

==================================
Path Count: 06672
New method: 0.189ms
Old method: 0.177ms

==================================
Path Count: 01168
New method: 0.032ms
Old method: 0.027ms
```

The new Method code:

```
Public Sub build_tree_recrusive()
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'create the root node
    root = New root_
    GC.Collect() ' clean up garbage if we just killed existing data
    root.n = New TreeNode
    root.n.SelectedImageIndex = 2
    root.n.ImageIndex = 2
    root.n.Text = frmTreeList.tv_filenames.SelectedNode.Text
    root.n.Name = "dir"
    frmTreeList.tv_contents.Nodes.Add(root.n) 'Add to treeview
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'now the fun up part. Create the nested tree structure.
    Dim indexes(9) As Integer 'used to keep track of where we are in the tree structure
    Dim isDir As Boolean = False ' flag for setting up image index
    For Each ent In current_package
        Dim ext = Path.GetExtension(ent.FileName)
        If ext.Length > 0 Then 'is this entry a file or directory?
            isDir = False
        Else
            isDir = True
        End If
        Dim a = ent.FileName.Split("/")

        rc(a, 0, 0, root, ent.FileName, isDir)

    Next 'each ent
End Sub
Private Function rc(ByRef a() As String, ByRef idx As Integer, ByRef ndx As Integer, ByRef node As root_, ByRef fullpath As String, ByVal isDir As Boolean) As Boolean
    If idx = a.Length Then Return True
    If a(idx) = "" Then Return True
    If node.find(a(idx), ndx) Then
        If rc(a, idx + 1, ndx, node.node(ndx), fullpath, isDir) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Else
        node.add(a(idx), ndx, fullpath, node.n, isDir)
        If rc(a, idx + 1, ndx, node.node(ndx), fullpath, isDir) Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```